# Parsing values between double quotes values from json list downloaded via curl

Tags: json, bash, parsing, curl

I have an online JSON file. Every time I try to download it. But I need to parse this JSON and get online ip's between double-quotes. Normally I can parse it with jq like .sample[].echo etc. but my list bigger than that example1,2..300 store more than 300 block data in it. I need to parse and get only inside of double quotes and get the all ip's.

By the way: I saw many questions on stackover but none of them related to filtering this kind of input

```
curl -L "https://sample.data.com/ip.json" -o 'ip.json' | *need to parsing method here*
```

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
  "sample1": {
    "echo": [
      "255.254.253.0/32"
    ],
    "delta": [
      "199.231.211.0/32"
    ]
  },
    "sample2": {
    "beta": [
      "250.123.124.0/32"
    ],
    "pre": [
      "122.156.243.0/32"
    ]
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `jq '.[][]'` (or `jq '.. | strings'`)?

Comment: @oguzismail didnt try it. I modified your answer and it worked. jq -r '.[][][]' this one worked.  `curl -s "https://sample.data.com/ip.json" | jq -r '.[][][]' > ip.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract all strings that looks like an IP, then you can still use `jq`. If we "fix" your example JSON above, to be actual JSON, then running the following jq program:

```
.. | strings | match("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?:/\\d+)?").string
```

over it would output:

```
"255.254.253.0/32"
"199.231.211.0/32"
"250.123.124.0/32"
"122.156.243.0/32"
```

I guess your don't want to keep the IPs quored, this can be handled with `-r` output flag

```
$ curl ... | jq -r '.. | strings | match("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?:/\\d+)?").string'
255.254.253.0/32
199.231.211.0/32
250.123.124.0/32
122.156.243.0/32
```

Comment: I found the answer with the above command but I am also curious about your way. I tried your way but did I wrong sth. because I could get any meaningful thing.
`curl -L "https://sample.data.com/ip.json" -o 'ip.json' | jq -r | strings | match("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?:/\\d+)?").string`
`curl -L "https://sample.data.com/ip.json" -o 'ip.json' | strings | match("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?:/\\d+)?").string`

Both try I get : `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?:/\\d+)?"'`

Comment: @hammer89 Why did you remove the quotes? And the `..` ?

Comment: `"255.254.253.0/32",
 "199.231.211.0/32",
 "250.123.124.0/32",
 "122.156.243.0/32"`

Can we get like this?

Comment: @hammer89 If you want to output an array, then wrap the output in one: `jq '[.. | strings | ....]`

Comment: before wrapping the array. I still couldnt run your answer properly, still getting syntax error with this command. `curl -L "https://sample.data.com/ip.json" -o 'ip.json' | strings | match("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+(?:/\\d+)?").string`  Can you write the full command please?

Comment: @hammer89 I have updated the answer to make it *hopefully* more clear, what is shell code and what is jq code.

Comment: It's worked, can you also update the first one that without -r? Thank you.